# How to determine if a Gradle task was instantiated (Configuration Avoidance API)

Tags: gradle, configuration, task, instantiation

I am trying to improve the performance of our Gradle builds and discovered the Gradle Task Configuration Avoidance API (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html). It allows to postpone the creation and configuration of a task, unless it is really needed. This might save a lot of startup time and as we call Gradle multiple times during a build, this could amount to considerable time savings.

We developed some plugins for internal use and I put an effort into changing how I define the tasks to avoid creation when not needed. I want to test if my changes are successful and the task instantiation is delayed.

Simple example of how to create a task without instantiating it:

```
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
}

TaskProvider customTask = tasks.register("customAction", MyTask) {
    println "task configured!"  // configuration time output
    doLast {
        println "action 1!"    // execution time output
    }
}

// configuration like this avoids task instantiation
tasks.named("customAction") {
    doLast {
        println "action 2!"
    }
}

tasks.withType(MyTask).configureEach {
    doLast {
        println "action 3!"
    }
}
```

Executing `gradle help` does not print the "task configured!" message, while `gradle customAction` does.

To make sure I do not accidentally trigger task instantiation, I would like to write tests for our plugins. But I could not find a way to determine if a task is instantiated or not.

I know about Build Scans (https://guides.gradle.org/creating-build-scans/), but our corporate guidelines are strict and clearance is pending, so I can not use it for now. Also, I do not see a way to use it in tests.

Is there a way to

- get a list of created/instantiated tasks from the Gradle project?
- or is there any property on Task or TaskProvider showing whether the task has been created/instantiated?
- or can buildscans be used offline somehow?

It would be cool, if the solution could be used in the plugin's test code, but manual evaluation would also be valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`configureEach` called only when task is created. you can write something like this to get list of all configured tasks

```
def tasks = []
project.allprojects { Project sp ->
    sp.tasks.configureEach { Task t ->
        tasks,add(t.path)
    }
}
project.gradle.buildFinished {
    println tasks
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the workaround I have been using and looks like this is the only solution. :/

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what OP asked for, but this will give you some stats on how many of each type of task were configured:

```
gradlew :help -Dorg.gradle.internal.tasks.stats
```